# how do I write a serial port GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I want create a "Serial Reader/Writer" in Python with Tkinter. For that I need a screen who appear the reading of the Serial Port and an entry with a button for send a string. Actually, I use this code without Tkinter and I can only send a message and then view the response on the console. My code :

```
import serial
while True:
    try:
        print("Enter the COM port, basicly is the COM3")
        COM = str(input())
        if COM=="":
            COM = "COM3"
        ser = serial.Serial(port=COM, baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=2)
        ser.isOpen()
        print("Serial Port is Open")
        if(ser.isOpen()):
            try:
                while(1):
                    msg = ser.readline()[:-2].decode("utf-8")
                    #data = msg.split("&")
                    if "Slave1" in msg:
                        print("SerialCOM> " + str(msg.replace("<PC&", "")))
                    else:
                        print("other> " + str(msg))
                    if(ser.read() == bytes("", 'utf-8')):
                        print()
                        print("Computer> Send message : ")
                        ser.write(bytes(input(), 'utf-8'))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error : " + str(e))
                print("Press enter to retry...")
                ser.close()
                wait = input()
                continue
        else:
            print("Cannot open the serial Port")
            wait = input()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error : " + str(e))
        ser.close()
        print("Press enter to retry...")
        wait = input()
        continue
```

I don't know how I can do for realize my project. I don't know where I must put the .mainloop() etc... in my code.
Thank you in advance for your assistance

One of my tries :

```python
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import serial
COM = "COM3"
ser = serial.Serial(port=COM, baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=2)
ser.isOpen()
def ReadSerial():
    global msg
    msg = ""
    msg = ser.readline()[:-2].decode("utf-8")
    if msg != "":
        print(msg)
    return msg
def WriteSerial(sendmsg):
    print("send")
    ser.write(bytes(sendmsg, 'utf-8'))
    ReadSerial()
def main():
    ReadSerial()
    root.after(200, main)

root = tk.Tk()
ReadSerial()
inputData = Entry(root)
readData = Label(root, text=msg)
entrymsg = inputData.get()
buttonMsg = Button(root, text="send", command = WriteSerial(entrymsg))
inputData.grid()
readData.grid()
buttonMsg.grid()

root.after(5, main)
root.mainloop()
```

In this try the problem is we can interact with the window only every 200ms (because I don't know how to do a multi-thread)

Comment: What attempts have you made so far to create a tkinter GUI? Odds are that you will either have to use `.after` to periodically read from the serial port or use a seperate thread to read from the port "in the background". Your question will likely be closed unless you edit your question to ask a more specific question rather than "how do I write a serial port GUI?"

Comment: I re-edited my post with what I had tested